# Everyday process in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a function that gets current currency of dollar from some site:

```
def update_currency(request):
    import urllib2
    import ast
    from django.conf import settings
    s = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange=&json&coursid=11').read(1000)
    data = ast.literal_eval(s)  #parse string list to list
    settings.CURRENCY_USD = float(data[2]['sale'])
    return redirect(reverse('manager_page'))
```

Manager update currency by pressing button. But what if manager forgot to do this, then currency is not actual. So I need this function to be called one time per day at some time. How to implement it?

I'm saving currency in `settings.py`, because this method `update_currency` takes a few seconds to get currency from server, and I don't want it every time a customer buy something

Comment: Have a look at [django-periodically](https://github.com/hzdg/django-periodically), it might suit your purpose.

Comment: The response from that server is JSON. Use `json.loads()` to parse it, not `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 5):

You can schedule routine tasks by **[CRON](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)** in CLI or **[Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)** in Django.
I suggesting you that follow below steps:

1. store data out of settings file(store in db or JSON file or XML file)
2. [Make a Django management instruction](http://thingsilearned.com/2009/03/13/adding-custom-commands-to-managepy-and-django-adminpy/) for example `update_currency` that running **`update_currency` function**.
3. make a CRON file or setup celery for running `./manage.py update_currency` command in certain time of days.

**Update:**
If you want store data in Database you can create new Model and make One-To-Many relation between this model to other models, i suggesting to you that override save method of this Model similar below:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Currency.objects.all().count()  > 0 and self != Currency.objects.all()[0]:
            obj = Currency.objects.all()[0]
            obj.value = self.value
            obj.save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super(Currency, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

by upon save method you have maximum only one instance in next times.

---

Also by thanks of @martinarroyo, [django-priodically](https://github.com/hzdg/django-periodically) project is very perfect and so useful.

Comment: Explain please, why I should not store currency in settings file? It's just one float value.

Comment: The backend logic of this suggest is that **hold external data out of hard code**, by this act your code is more reliable.

Comment: If I store it in database, there are two way: or to create new model with one field, or add this field to existing model, but then there will be as many currency fields as model instances. What's better way?

Comment: Post updated... your answer is in updated section :-)

Comment: Is it a singleton pattern?

Comment: YES but only in db, you can make multiple instance of this class in same time, **Is it a model by one record in database**