# Refreshing fields of Django model regularly

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a Django site with an Article model. I want to sort by the most shared article.

How do I frequently check how many shares an article has? Maybe daily?

I could create a cronjob but I was hoping to do it all within Django. I was thinking maybe every time the model is fetched, I could refresh/refetch the share count? However, I think that would be a bit overkill and eat up my resources.

Comment: how many times you need to check depends solely on your business logic

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggest for you to do it:

1. **[Update info periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367153/everyday-process-in-django-python/30367374#30367374)**
   by using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) project instead of crontab you can update information by scheduling in python and django.
2. **[Update info by Django ORM signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/)**
   Django ORM fire signals for some main actions such as create, update and delete a row of db tables, you can connect functions to this signals for updating info, if you store share info to db.